# I'm trying to copy the numbers in one to array to another but I keep getting "Index was outside the bounds of the array" and don't know why

Tags: c#

I'm trying to copy the numbers of one array to the second and then printing out both but I keep getting this error and have no idea why. I'm a complete beginner so I'm sorry if this was a dumb question. the error occurs for `copy[index] = array[index];`

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     int[] array = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

     int[] copy = new int[] {array.Length};

     for (int index = 0; index < array.Length; index++)
          copy[index] = array[index]; 

     for (int index = 0; index < array.Length; index++)
     {
          Console.Write(array[index] + " ");
     }

     Console.WriteLine();

     for (int index = 0; index < array.Length; index++)
     {
          Console.Write(copy[index] + " ");
     }
     Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `copy` array is only one element in length:

```
int[] copy = new int[] {array.Length};
```

It's an array of length `1` and its first (only) element is the value `10`.  As such, as soon as you try to access `copy[1]` you are outside the bounds of that array.

I suspect you meant to initialize it like this:

```
int[] copy = new int[array.Length];
```

Answer (score 1):

The line:

```
 int[] copy = new int[] {array.Length};
```

Creates an Array with only one element: the int represented by `array.length`. This means that trying to access any index other than `0` will throw an error. You want to initialize the size:

```
 int[] copy = new int[array.Length];
```